# How to start and bind a service without race conditions?

Tags: android, android-service, race-condition, android-binder

I'm trying to create a service that is *primarily* run in the foreground and clients can bind to it only if it is already in the started state. However, every potential solution I can come up with is riddled with race conditions.

The most promiment example of this:

```java
final ServiceConnection serviceConnection = // create instance...

void startAndBindToService() {
    final Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);

    startService(serviceIntent);
    
    // this *sometimes* doesn't bind because the service isn't started yet
    bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConnection, 0);  
}
```

Testing on an emulator, the above works consistently on a **local** service but not when the service is in another process.

I've also looked into having the service starting itself when its `onBind` method is called:

```java
@Override
public void IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    startService(new Intent(this, this.getClass()));
    return binder;
}
```

But this never guarantees the service will be in the started state before the client unbinds.

And for the ones that think they are clever and ask why I don't use `BIND_AUTO_CREATE`, that doesn't solve the problem, and in fact it only makes it worse. `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` only creates the service, it doesn't put it in the started state, but it does allow for the service to end being created twice if a race condition does occur.

Comment: I also wanted add. One can just start a service and use a handler and repeatedly try to bind to the service every x milliseconds, but that isn't a very elegant solution.

Comment: I'm curious if your app contains the service you're trying to bind to, because it sounds like whoever wrote it did not properly implement onBind or onStartCommand (or both).  If you're offering a bindable service, any initialization done in onStartCommand should also happen in onBind.  Because either one can be used to launch a service.

Comment: As stated in Android's documentation-  generally you implement onBind OR onStartCommand, not both (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services).  There are exceptions.  But the idea is that binding circumvents the normal onStart functionality.  When a Service is meant to run in either mode, onBind should be responsible for starting itself, or just running the same init code.